# Eloquent : querying models depending on model's relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm looking for a way to query models depending on the existence of the model's relationships.

http://paste.laravel.com/xuh Here's a paste with what I'm looking to accomplish.

The basic idea would be to search for Collections only where the User has access in the `shared_access` table.

Dreamcode (doesn't work):

```
Collection::where('sharedAccess.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id->get())
```

Comment: are you getting any error? what is the output?

Comment: what is the schema of the tables?how collection and sharedAccess tables are related?foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [fancy has() method](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations). It basically allows you to do things like this:

```
Collection::has('sharedAccess')->get();
```

That would fetch all collections that have a related `SharedAccess` instance.